# Sum values in a field for selected features QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm a new user trying to perform very simple operation but I'm completely stuck. I'd like to be able to select a number of features on the map and then get the sum of a particular field for only the selected features, on the fly. For example, summing the population fields for a number of counties that I've selected on the map. I don't need to store the sum in any way, I just need to quickly get it for reference.

Comment: That sounds like it would be a useful feature, but I don't think it exists in QGIS, at least not without writing code for it yourself. The fastest other way I can think of is to copy the selected features and paste into a spreadsheet.

Comment: Actually, it looks like there is a way to do this, using the "show statistical" button on the attributes toolbar. I'll post this as an answer as soon as my computer stops being slow.

Comment: Thank you. I think you're right. QGIS 3 has an "execute SQL" function that seemed promising, it looks like it isn't strictly for queries/selection as it can apply a SQL operation to only the selected features. But I'm using QGIS 2 for this project because there's way more information online.

Comment: This is what I love about stack exchange. I didn't know this feature existed until I read this question and went looking for it. Now that I know it exists I'm sure I'll use the stats panel all the time.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The **Statistics Panel** displays various calculations based on a field.

- To open the Statistics Panel, click the epsilon button in the Attributes toolbar.
- Select the layer from the dropdown menu at the top of the stats panel.
- Select the field from the dropdown menu below that.
- At the bottom of the panel, check the box for "selected features only." Otherwise statistics are calculated for all features in the layer.
- To choose what types of stats are calculated, use the "..." button at the bottom-right of the panel.

[image]

Screenshot is from QGIS 2.18. The stats panel also exists in QGIS 3.0.

Comment: Please use the check mark next to the answer to accept it. This way other people with the same question will know that this answer is correct.

Comment: Note: If you want to sum, for example Area (which hasn't been pre-calculated in an attribute table), you'll need to set the Field Selector/Expression dialog to something like $area. This will give you a summary of the area in the CRS' base unit.